# Handling workplace complaints for a previous employer

Tags: management, human-resources

About a year ago I moved on from a job where I was an executive. Since then, I've kept in touch with some of the employees there. They tell me about all of the great things they are accomplishing, and some of the silly things they have to muddle their way through.

Then I am told about things that didn't happen while I was there, things I would consider serious. For example, discrimination. Those that have spoken to me about it sometimes mention it casually, other times they ask me for advice. My go to answer is they need to go to HR and have the company investigate it.

How should I handle these types of inquiries? I'd dislike shutting them out completely, but I also don't feel it is my place to be handling these kinds of issues. I also don't feel it is my place to reach out to HR directly myself.

Comment: Small note: keeping in touch with colleagues that you consider friends is fine. Keeping in touch when you otherwise wouldn't speak to these people in order to maintain a link to a former employer is unhealthy at best.

Comment: @Lilienthal Isn't that considered networking?  Not because of the former employer connection, but because they are former co-workers.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Depends on your definition of networking, how regular the contact is and how much value these former colleagues have to OP's network. I raised the issue because all too often people remain too invested in what happens at their former workplace and would benefit from severing the relationship entirely or at least reducing the amount of contact they initiate or respond to.

Answer (score 7):

It's not your place to try and rectify their problems on the limited knowledge they're giving you. Or at all for that matter.

I keep in touch with many people and hear a lot of things. I disregard anything I can't use for my own advantage in some way as hearsay. I certainly won't get involved in their problems at their workplace. Your stock answer of 'go to HR' is about as far as I would get involved.